# Loading up large datastructure on init for repeated use by celery task later (Django/Celery)

Tags: django, celery

One of my celery tasks requires access to a very large data structure. This model is taxing on memory once loaded up and takes a very long time to do so.

I am trying to avoid loading this multiple times, every time I call "score_model". Preferably, I'd like to load this data into memory once at initialisation so that it is available only to this task when required.

*(Usually pickle works great however this model does not serialise easily and so I cannot set it within cache. It would require a complex custom backend and I'm not convinced it would result in significant time savings.)*

The celery docs suggest I should create a base class. This SO answer was also very helpful [Initializing a worker with arguments using Celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070485/initializing-a-worker-with-arguments-using-celery)

The answer hints at having objects made available upon initialisation for use later and works well for centralising common functions, keeping sessions open when used across workers. **The following code works:**

```
tasks.py

from celery import Task
from celery.decorators import task

class startup(Task):
    abstract = True
    def __init__(self):
        print "Loading..."
        self.score_model= load_and_bin('/opt/model.tar')

@task(base=startup, bind=True, name="scoring")       
def scoring(self, pk):
    data = entries.objects.filter(geo_pk=pk)
    newscores = score_model(data)
```

...however this loads my model into memory multiple times upon initialisation - even starting up celery beat (which does not run this task) or even flower. I can see that little print more than once and I'm not sure why. So I quickly run out of resources. Registering this class, by removing abstract=True, still works but I run out of resources more quickly.

How can I run load_and_bin once, and have this object available later on? I start celery with: `celery -A app worker`